# No encuentro el directorio donde según se guardan las imágenes

Tags: flutter

Tengo una pantalla que accede a la galeria para seleccionar imagenes. Despues de seleccionar las imagenes se deberia de guardar en una ruta que es la siguiente: ***Imagen guardada en: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DA34D6CB-8E50-4474-8FDB-BCCB0722F558/Documents/my_images_folder/image_picker_10B6C77B-F45C-4B95-B052-B7E5B1A2E541-11862-00000BDD4E44CA7C.jpg***

El problema es que no esta dicho directorio creado en el teléfono.
Saben el motivo por el cual no esta el directorio cuando según si se creo y se guardo la imagen renombrada.

> Código del proceso:

```
Future<void> saveFilesToInternalStorage(List<XFile> images) async {
  try {

    var statusPermission = await Permission.storage.request();
    // var statusPermission = await Permission.storage.status;

    if (statusPermission.isGranted) {
      // Obtener el directorio de documentos de la aplicación
      Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      if (documentsDirectory != null) {
        print('Directorio de almacenamiento interno: ${documentsDirectory.path}');

        // Crear una carpeta dentro del directorio de documentos
        Directory folderDirectory =
            Directory('${documentsDirectory.path}/my_images_folder');
        if (!folderDirectory.existsSync()) {
          folderDirectory.createSync();
        }

        // Iterar sobre las imágenes y guardarlas en la carpeta
        for (XFile image in images) {
          String imageName = image.path.split('/').last;
          String imagePath = '${folderDirectory.path}/$imageName';

          // Copiar la imagen al directorio de la carpeta
          await File(image.path).copy(imagePath);
          print('Imagen guardada en: $imagePath');
        }
      } else {
        print('No se pudo obtener el directorio de almacenamiento interno.');
      }
    } else {
      print('No se tiene permisos para guardar las imagenes.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
```